# Filter Date Column and Create New Column If True or False

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to create a new column in my dataframe called "Dates", where there is a true or false listed given the criteria df['CURRENT_DATE'] < '2016-06-30'. 
If the datetime object listed in the CURRENT_DATE column is < 2016-06-30, then I want 'TRUE' to be listed in my new 'Dates' column. If it does not meet the criteria I would like 'FALSE' to be listed under the new 'Dates' column.

Here is my code:

```
def find_dates(df):
    if df['MATURITY_DATE'] < '2016-06-30' :
        return 'True'
    else: 
        return 'False'

df['Dates'] = df.apply(find_dates, axis = 1)
```

I get back the error: TypeError: ("can't compare datetime.datetime to str", u'occurred at index 0')

Suggestions?

Comment: do you know how to convert a string into a datetime format?

Comment: please post the output of `df.info()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
df["Dates"] = df["MATURITY_DATE"] < pd.to_datetime('2016-06-30')
```